# opentbs doesn't print last row on xlsx

Tags: templates, xlsx, opentbs

I'm trying to print a XLSX file with OpenTBS. The issue us that I can't get the last row printed. Instead, OpenTBS just let the code ([base_sub2_sub1.respostas_dadas]) stay there, on the merged file.

```
[base;block=begin;sub1=answers;sub2=possible_answers;sub3=companies]
[base_sub1.question_code] - [base_sub1.questions;block=tbs:cell]
[base_sub3.name;block=tbs:row;sub1=answers_company] [base_sub3_sub1.answers;block=tbs:cell]
[base_sub2.answer;block=tbs:cell;sub1=total_answers]
[base_sub2_sub1.respostas_dadas;block=tbs:cell]
[base;block=end]


[base;block=row+row+row+row+row+row+row;sub1=answers;sub2=possible_answers;sub3=companies]
[base_sub1.question_code] - [base_sub1.questions;block=tbs:cell]
[base_sub3.name;block=tbs:row;sub1=answers_company]    
[base_sub3_sub1.answers;block=tbs:cell]
[base_sub2.answer;block=tbs:cell;sub1=total_answers]
[base_sub2_sub1.respostas_dadas;block=tbs:cell]
```

A screenshot from the template:
[image]

I already checked the data from mysql and it's all there.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tag `[base_sub2_sub1;...]` is not merged because it is out of the block "base_sub2" So it cannot be a sub-block of "base_sub2".

The block "base_sub2" is defined over a cell, while block "base_sub2_sub1" is defined over a row and below "base_sub2".

You have to change the bound of "base_sub2".

---

I have a comment about using the explicit syntax "block=begin" and "block=end" with OpenTBS. Such syntax may split the inner XML in an unexpected way. It is better to expend the TBS tag to a visible entity in order to avoid internal split.

So there is your alternative : "block=row+row+row+row+row+row+row".

But you can also use :

```
[base;block=begin;enlarge=tbs:row;...]
...
[base;block=end;enlarge=tbs:row]
```